# html5: placing a text and an image side by side horizontally with dotted border between them

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a text and an image that I want to put side by side horizontally inside a bordered section. And want to have a vertical dotted border between them. How do I do that? Below code puts them one after another.

```css
.borderexample {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#287EC7;
}
```

```html
<section class="borderexample" id="data_zone"></section>
<script>
    var color = "some text";
    document.querySelector('#data_zone').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' +
        color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="badsign" src="fp2.jpeg" />';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Without knowing exactly what visual result you're hoping to acheive, it is difficult to know exactly what to show you. But here is one method.

I have also added some *padding* using [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and [vertically aligned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) the image.

```css
.borderexample {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#287EC7;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px dotted black;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
p:after {
    margin-right: 1em;
    content: "";
}
img:before {
    margin-left: 1em;
    content: "";
}
```

```html
<section class="borderexample" id="data_zone"></section>
<script>
    var color = "some text";
    document.querySelector('#data_zone').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' +
        color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="badsign" src="fp2.jpeg" />';
</script>
```

### Applying the border directly to the `<img>`

After your comment below, I wonder if this might be a *better* approach?

I have also simplified the CSS, and removed the use of pseudo elements.

```css
.borderexample {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #287EC7;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle; /* optional */
    border-left: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<section class="borderexample" id="data_zone"></section>
<script>
    var color = "some text";
    document.querySelector('#data_zone').innerHTML = '<p><strong>' +
        color + '</strong></p>' + '<img id="badsign" src="fp2.jpeg" />';
</script>
```

Comment: works but the image is not right alined (not towards the right border wall).

Comment: @lilyhack - Could you edit your question to show a mock-up of the desired result? A simple image created using Photoshop or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) would suffice. Without knowing the typical image dimensions, if they might change, the length of the text, and how it should display *etc.* it is difficult to offer you much more than a basic first step.

Comment: @lilyhack - are you trying to give the image a dotted left border?

Answer (score 1):

You can make the parent `display: flex;`, wrap the `img` in an element so it doesn't `stretch`, then use a `border` either on the `p` or the element that wraps the image to draw the dotted vertical line.

```css
.borderexample {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #287EC7;
  display: flex;
}
p {
  border-right: 2px dotted #287EC7;
  padding-right: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="borderexample" id="data_zone">

</section>

<script>
  var color = "color";
  document.querySelector("#data_zone").innerHTML =
    "<p><strong>" +
    color +
    "</strong></p>" +
    '<div><img id="badsign" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" /><div>';
</script>
```

Comment: I see its working in your case but doesn't work with my jpg image. The dotted line shows after the image

Comment: nevermind, it works. Just not right aligned. I added float:right but it takes to image to center!       img {
  max-width: 20%;
  float: right;
}

Comment: @lilyhack cool did you get it working or do you still need help? Did you not want the border to go from top to bottom of the parent?